Average of multiple ggpredict objects
I have generated 10 model summaries after fitting the same model on 10 different subsets of the dataset which is as follows
library(mice)
data("nhanes")
head(nhanes)

imp <- mice(nhanes, print = FALSE, m = 10, seed = 24415)
df <- complete(imp, "long")
model_fit <- lapply(1:10, function(i) {
  model = lm(bmi ~ age + hyp + chl,
             data = subset(df, `.imp`==i))
})

From this I get different ggpredict objects
ggpredict(model_fit[[1]], c("age", "hyp"))
ggpredict(model_fit[[2]], c("age", "hyp"))
ggpredict(model_fit[[3]], c("age", "hyp"))
ggpredict(model_fit[[4]], c("age", "hyp"))
ggpredict(model_fit[[5]], c("age", "hyp"))
ggpredict(model_fit[[6]], c("age", "hyp"))
ggpredict(model_fit[[7]], c("age", "hyp"))
ggpredict(model_fit[[8]], c("age", "hyp"))
ggpredict(model_fit[[9]], c("age", "hyp"))
ggpredict(model_fit[[10]], c("age", "hyp"))

I am looking for an efficient way to a) Estimate the average of all the ggpredict objects by hp and age
The expected output would look like this.
  age    hp      Predicted                        95% C.I
  --------------------------------------------------------
  1      1       (28.38 + 29.35 + 27.3...)/10      (26.67 +2 6.83 + 25.25...)/10 ; (30.08 + 31.87 + 29.35....)/10 
  2      1       (24.21 + 26.01 + 25.40...)/10     (22.71 + 23.56 + 23.54...)/10 ;  (25.71 + 28.46 + 27.26....)/10
  3      1       (20.05 + 22.67 + 23.51...)/10     (17.13 + 17.89 + 20.08..)/10 ;   (22.96 + 27.44 + 26.94...)/10

  1      2       (31.82 + 29.35 +28.87...)/10    (28.07 + 23.58 + 24.24...)/10 ;  (35.58 + 35.13 + 33.49....)/10 
  2      2       (27.66 + 26.01 +26.97...)/10    (24.88 + 22.02 + 23.43...)/10 ;  (30.43 + 30.00 + 30.52....)/10  
  3      2       (23.49 + 22.67 +25.08...)/10    (20.63 + 18.73 + 21.50...)/10 ;  (26.35 + 26.61 + 28.66....)/10     

b) Plot based on the final averaged values using ggplot function.

So far I tried storing the results from each ggpredict function as list object and
`Reduce(`+`, list_ggpred)/length(list_ggpred)`

I got warning,
 " In Ops.factor(left, right) : `+1 not meaningful for factors.

Any suggestions highly appreciated. Thanks.

Simply use pool_predictions():
library(ggeffects)
# example for multiple imputed datasets
data("nhanes2", package = "mice")
imp <- mice::mice(nhanes2, printFlag = FALSE)
predictions <- lapply(1:5, function(i) {
  m <- lm(bmi ~ age + hyp + chl, data = mice::complete(imp, action = i))
  predict_response(m, "age")
})
pool_predictions(predictions)
#> # Predicted values of bmi
#> 
#> age   | Predicted |       95% CI
#> --------------------------------
#> 20-39 |     30.09 | 28.17, 32.02
#> 40-59 |     24.60 | 21.48, 27.72
#> 60-99 |     21.75 | 18.24, 25.26
#> 
#> Adjusted for:
#> * hyp =     no
#> * chl = 196.32

# and:
# pool_predictions(predictions) |> plot()

Created on 2024-04-30 with reprex v2.1.0
Note that pool_predictions() account for the missing values / multiple imputations and adjusts the standard error, thus you get slightly larger confidence intervals than just taking the mean.

Like this?
library(mice)
library(ggeffects)
library(tidyverse)

imp <- mice(nhanes, print = FALSE, m = 10, seed = 24415)
df <- complete(imp, "long")
model_fit <- lapply(1:10, function(i) {
  model = lm(bmi ~ age + hyp + chl,
             data = subset(df, `.imp`==i))
})

map(model_fit, ggpredict, c("age", "hyp")) |> 
  bind_rows(.id = "id") |> 
  rename(age = x, hyp = group) |> 
  as_tibble() |> 
  summarise(across(c(predicted, conf.low, conf.high), mean), .by = c(age, hyp))
#> # A tibble: 6 × 5
#>     age hyp   predicted conf.low conf.high
#>   <dbl> <fct>     <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1     1 1          28.6     26.5      30.6
#> 2     1 2          30.7     26.4      35.0
#> 3     2 1          25.2     23.3      27.0
#> 4     2 2          27.3     24.1      30.5
#> 5     3 1          21.8     18.3      25.2
#> 6     3 2          23.9     20.5      27.2

Created on 2024-04-24 with reprex v2.1.0

I may have misunderstood, but one potential option could be:
library(mice)
library(ggeffects)

data("nhanes")
head(nhanes)
#>   age  bmi hyp chl
#> 1   1   NA  NA  NA
#> 2   2 22.7   1 187
#> 3   1   NA   1 187
#> 4   3   NA  NA  NA
#> 5   1 20.4   1 113
#> 6   3   NA  NA 184
imp <- mice(nhanes, print = FALSE, m = 10, seed = 24415)
df <- complete(imp, "long")
model_fit <- lapply(1:10, function(i) {
  model = lm(bmi ~ age + hyp + chl,
             data = subset(df, `.imp`==i))
})

library(tidyverse)
list_of_results <- map(model_fit, ggpredict, c("age", "hyp"))
ggpredicts <- map(list_of_results, `[[`, "predicted")
map(ggpredicts, mean)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 25.93424
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 26.01019
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] 26.18797
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] 26.69359
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> [1] 25.90896
#> 
#> [[6]]
#> [1] 26.26845
#> 
#> [[7]]
#> [1] 26.10574
#> 
#> [[8]]
#> [1] 25.81957
#> 
#> [[9]]
#> [1] 26.34521
#> 
#> [[10]]
#> [1] 26.89521

df <- bind_cols(map(ggpredicts, mean))
colnames(df) <- paste0("Model_", str_pad(1:10, 2, pad = "0"))
df %>%
  pivot_longer(everything(),
               values_to = "mean prediction",
               names_to = "model") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = `model`, y = `mean prediction`)) +
  geom_col() +
  theme_bw()


Created on 2024-04-24 with reprex v2.1.0
Is that close to your expected outcome?

my apologies for not being clear, I have updated my question with more details. Is this helpful ?
